# Preventing kids from deleting a folder

Tags: file-management

I have an old Samsung mobile with android 4.1. I have downloaded some cartoons for kids which they frequently enjoy. However, sometimes the kids accidently delete the cartoons and I have to download them again. So my question is that how can I write-protect this "cartoon" folder so that the kids can only watch the cartoons but cannot delete this cartoon folder?
Regards

Comment: What file format is used by your "Cartoons"? Or ist it a special app?

Answer (score 1):

Hiding all apps from default launcher except mxplayer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this apk, Hope this can help you. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kidscrape.king&hl=es

Comment: Thanks, but this app does not serve the purpose. The purpose is to allow kids to play their cartoons on their own, without being able to delete them.

Comment: ok, your phone is root?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible to make a file read only on an unrooted android device. 
If it were me, I would put shortcuts on the home screen to make accidental deletion a little less likely and create backup copies of the cartoons in order not to have to download again if they do get trashed. All of this can be done easily with any decent file manager.

Answer (score -1):

If you undertake deletion and want to return it but do not use app from google. Then you can still delete it using another third party app. The way is easy enough you stay following the following ways :

1. First of all you download and install the app in google play store named Diskdigger.
2. Next open the application, it will appear some existing photo files.
3. If you want to restore data in the form of video then you need to root hp android first.
4. Then you can use the application and select the file you want to restore and click restore.